# In Steamboy, what is the purpose of that equipment on this back and the bottle on his waist?

Tags: steamboy

In Steamboy (Same director as Akira), what is the purpose of that equipment on this back and the bottle on his waist?

When he puts on the aero corps uniform, he also puts on that backpack and bottle as well. Far as I can see, he never uses for anything. And he just carries it on his back only to take it off without ever using it for anything.

Comment: From someone who hasn't seen the series, I have to ask an ignorant question. Presumably he used steam for power, and that the steam was stored as water. Where was the water stored, and what made the steam?

Comment: With the understanding that this is purely science fiction the premise of the movie is that if you can fill a container which can retain the heat of the hot water and is also strong enough to maintain a ludacris amount of pressure you could use this container of pressurized hot water as a kind of power source.

Comment: Okay, so the water/steam container is separate from the bottle at his waist. It certainly sounds like you were paying attention, so maybe the movie just didn't say what the bottle and backpack were for.  Hopefully it was explained in the source material, and someone who read that knows the answer.